# $p$-primary component of the $G$-module "commutes" with cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

This question is related to a claim found in J-P. Serre's *Galois Cohomology*.

Let $G$ be a profinite group (or finite if you like) and $A$ be a torsion discrete $G$-module.

Serre says one can easily see that we can identify the $p$-primary component $H^{q}(G,A)(p)$ of $H^{q}(G,A)$ with the group $H^{q}(G,A(p))$, where $A(p)$ denotes the $ p$-primary component of $A$.

Any hints on how to prove this? Thank you!

**EDIT**: The answer provided reduces this to showing $H^{q}(G,A)$ is $p$-torsion, for $A$ $p$-primary. (See the comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ is torsion, it is the direct sum of its $\ell$-torsion components over all primes $\ell$.  We thus have $H^q(G,A)\cong\bigoplus_\ell H^q(G,A(\ell))$.  Since $H^q(G,A(\ell))$ is $\ell$-torsion for each $\ell$, the $p$-torsion component of $\bigoplus_\ell H^q(G,A(\ell))$ is just the summand $H^q(G,A(p))$.

Comment: Can you explain why $H^{q}(G,A)$ is $p$-torsion for a $p$-primary $A$? On the cocycle/coboundary level, I don't see any reason for this, because the $p$-torsion on $A$ is not generally "bounded", so I think we can't really find a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to force the function $p^{n}f\colon G^{q}\to A$ to be identically zero (which is one possible attempt, since the zero map is a coboundary), so we must really show that it becomes a coboundary.

Comment: Any continuous map $G^q\to A$ has finite image, so there is a single $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^n$ annihilates every element of its image.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks!